# Como usar uma só autenticação laravel para todos os subdomínios de um mesmo domínio?

Tags: laravel, autenticação

Preciso utilizar uma só autenticação num projeto laravel, que está no `subdominio1.dominio.com.br`. Neste subdomínio terá uma autenticação, e tá funcionando normalmente, via banco de dados `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database')` lá no `session.php`.
Tenho um outro subdomínio, `subdominio2.dominio.com.br`, e quero usar a mesma autenticação que já foi feita no `subdominio1.dominio.com.br`, usando a mesma tabela de users para todos os subdomínios.
Como faço pra usar esta mesma autenticação em todos os subdomínios?

Comment: Os dois subdominios vão apontar para a mesma pasta 'public' do projeto? Ou serão totalmente independentes?

Comment: Vão apontar para a mesma pasta public sim. Se puder me ajudar com isso também, agradeço.

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema!